# how to display posts from 2 categories (both at the same time) inside the archives page

Tags: wordpress, categories

Hi I have some links inside the archives page and I want to filter the content how can I create a link to give me posts from both categories category A and category B only. 
my working example is this http://myurl.com/?cat=39,38,-37,-29,-36,-4,-11,-6,-27,-30
but it's not seo friendly I want something like this http://myurl.com/?cat=39and38

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do that is to create and use a custom page template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Next in the custom page template, create a loop you want using `query_posts()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Both links are a great place to start.

Back to your question: I think http://myurl.com/?cat=39&cat=38 will work, have you try it?

Comment: thanks for your help I am trying to avoid custom pages cause I would end with 32 pages custom pages. I have tried ?cat=39&cat=38 but it gives me all the cat=39 alone + cat=38 alone + the result I want only posts from both categories.

Comment: No you don't have to. You can use conditional tags on the custom page, so you will only create one.

Comment: I made a custom page this is the only think working as it should be <?php query_posts(array('category__and' => array(4,36),'orderby'=>title,'order'=>ASC)); ?> I can't think conditional tags I have the archive page that displays everything and there I have some links from the categories I want to filter I point all the links to the custom page can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do
http://myurl.com/?cat=39,38 
with only a coma, it works for me

It's maybe a bit late for you, but it can help others